# Surprising equality regarding a partition of $\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}.$

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

> Let $A=\{1,2,\ldots,2n\},$ where $n\in\mathbb{N}.$ Partition $A$ into two disjoint subsets $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\cup Y=A$ and $|X|=|Y|=n.$ List the elements of $X$ in ascending order, $x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_n.$ List the elements of $Y$ in descending order, $y_1>y_2>\ldots>y_n.$ Show that $|x_1-y_1|+|x_2-y_2|+\ldots+|x_n-y_n|=n^2.$

My Proof:

For this proof, we need a few terms and a lemma first. Let $a\in A.$ If $a\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\},$ call it "small". Else, call it "large".

Lemma: Let $i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}.$ Then, $x_i$ is small $\iff y_i$ is large.

Proof of Lemma: Suppose $x_i$ is small. Suppose, to the contrary, $y_i$ is also small. Since the elements of $Y$ are descending, the next $n-i$ elements of $Y$ must also be small. Since the elements of $X$ are ascending, the previous $i-1$ elements of $X$ must also be small. Moreover, since $X\cap Y=\emptyset,$ we get that there are atleast $n-i+1+i-1+1$ small elements. $n-i$ comes from elements succeeding $y_i,$ the next $1$ comes from $y_i$ itself, $i-1$ comes from elements preceding $x_i,$ and the last $1$ comes from $x_i$ itself. So we get that there are atleast $n+1$ small elements, a clear contradiction. Now suppose $y_i$ and $x_i$ are large. The $n-i$ elements succeeding $x_i$ must also be large. The $i-1$ elements preceding $y_i$ must also be large. $x_i$ and $y_i$ themselves are large. Hence, there are atleast $n-i+i-1+2=n+1$ large elements, a clear contradiction.

To me, this proof is quite subtle. It seems as though we are not even using the hypothesis of $x_i$ being small or $y_i$ being large to show that $y_i$ is large or that $x_i$ is small, respectively. But it is these terms that contribute to the $+1$ in $n+1$ and hence give us our contradiction.

Anyway, from the lemma, we get:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n|x_i-y_i|=\sum_{x_i\text{ is small}}|x_i-y_i|+\sum_{x_i\text { is large}}|x_i-y_i|=\sum_{x_i\text{ is small}}(y_i-x_i)+\sum_{x_i\text{ is large}}(x_i-y_i).$$

It is easy to see that this is the sum of all large elements minus the sum of all small elements. This is equal to $n(2n+1)-n(n+1).$ This is equal to $n^2,$ as required.

Does this look right? It's a long read, but I think it's worth it because I think this should be known to more people. At first glance, I did not even expect this to be true. Over all $\frac{1}{2}{2n\choose n}$ possible equal-size partitions of $A$ into two sets, this weird looking sum is invariant and is equal to $n^2,$ of all things.

PS: I am not quite sure what branch of math this falls into, but the proof seems very combinatorial to me, so I'll be using the combinatorics tag.

Comment: On AoPS: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1131859p5262520, https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1715901p11083610. Also here: https://www.cut-the-knot.org/Curriculum/Games/ProizvolovGame.shtml.

Comment: Also on this site: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2503336/42969

Comment: In https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3494202/42969 it is shown that $\min\{a_k,b_k\} \le n < \max\{a_k,b_k\}$, that corresponds to your statement *“$x_i$  is small $\iff y_i$ is large”.* – Can we close this as a duplicate?