# Prove this equality holds: $|a_1 -b_1|+|a_2 -b_2|+|a_3 -b_3|+|a_4 -b_4|+|a_5 -b_5| = 25$.

Tags: combinatorics, summation

*This is the full problem*:
Numbers 1, 2, 3,... , 10 are divided to two disjoint sets {$a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$} and {$b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5$} such that:\begin{gather*}
    a_1 < a_2 < a_3 < a_4 < a_5 \text, \\
    b_1 > b_2 > b_3 > b_4 > b_5 \text.
    \end{gather*}

Prove that the equality $|a_1 -b_1|+|a_2 -b_2|+|a_3 -b_3|+|a_4 -b_4|+|a_5 -b_5| = 25$ is true for all sets {$a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4, a_5$} and {$b_1, b_2, b_3, b_4, b_5$}. *I have been stuck on this problem, I have some ideas like taking the average of the sums, but that led me nowhere. Thank you for your help!*

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Asked and answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2503336/42969

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thanks for your help. I will be more careful next time.